# filter an NSArray, which contains NSDictionary within NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to filter a `NSArray` which contains objects which are `NSDictionary`. This `NSDictionary` again contains `NSDictionary` inside it.

It looks something like this.

```
[
  {
    Comp_Name =      {
        text = "Quality Ace #5846-C";
    };
    ShipTo =         {
        text = 312025846;
    };
    SoldTo =         {
        text = 10000081;
    };
  },
  {
    Comp_Name =      {
        text = "Billington Ace Hardware  - 5863K";
    };
    ShipTo =         {
        text = 312025863;
    };
    SoldTo =         {
        text = 10000081;
    };
  }
]
```

I want to filter this Array to some "text" which matches with object for "Comp_Name".

Code that I am using is:

```
_filteredList = [_unFilteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Comp_Name == %@", searchBar.text]];
```

Please help me getting a filtered list based on object "Comp_Name", "text".

Comment: Shouldn't the predicate be @"Comp_Name.text == %@"?

Comment: I tried that as well. Doesn't seems to be working. I am getting an empty array as result.

Comment: Perhaps it's the missing quotes around the string. Use @"Comp_Name.text == '%@'".

Comment: Got it....I was using @"Comp_Name.text" == %@" instead of @"Comp_Name.text contains[cd] %@". Second one worked for me. Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: Your question says "matches", not "contains".

Comment: Well my main problem was, I did not know how to apply predicate the way you suggested. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmaddy - Thanks for help!!! `@"Comp_Name.text == %@"` works just fine.